# Proof of integral identity

Tags: solution-verification

I was looking for a proof of this identity:
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\phi \Delta\phi = - \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\nabla\phi|^2
\end{equation}
given $\phi \in C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Comment: I'm assuming $\phi: \Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$? In that case write $\Delta \phi=\nabla\boldsymbol{\cdotp}\nabla\phi$ and use the divergence theorem.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is a surface term,$$\int_{\Bbb R^n}(\phi\nabla^2\phi+\nabla\phi\cdot\nabla\phi)d^nx=\int_{\Bbb R^n}\nabla\cdot(\phi\nabla\phi)d^nx.$$